# How reasonable/possible/difficult is it to write a tsocks clone in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, network-programming, system

I'm a reasonably competent programmer who knows haskell, but who hasn't used it in any major projects.  I know enough about c and systems and network programming that I believe I can pick apart [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/about.php) from the source code.

I don't have any experience with the low-level systems interfaces haskell provides.  I'm looking for any advice people can offer me on the topic, including, "Don't do it; you'll hate yourself for it," provided there is an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really wouldn't do this, except as an experiment. I'm a Haskell guy, but not a deep systems guy, so there's a caveat there. But nonetheless, I see the following on the tsocks page:

> tsocks is based on the 'shared library
>   interceptor' concept. Through use of
>   the LD_PRELOAD environment variable or
>   the /etc/ld.so.preload file tsocks is
>   automatically loaded into the process
>   space of every executed program. From
>   there it overrides the normal
>   connect() function by providing its
>   own. Thus when an application calls
>   connect() to establish a TCP
>   connection it instead passes control
>   to tsocks. tsocks determines if the
>   connection needs to be made via a
>   SOCKS server (by checking
>   /etc/tsocks.conf) and negotiates the
>   connection if so (through use of the
>   real connect() function )

It is possible to call Haskell from C, and vice-versa. And its relatively easy, in fact. For shared libraries, see this: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/using-shared-libs.html.

But when you invoke Haskell from C, you need to A) link in the runtime and B) invoke the runtime.

So that works when the C knows that its calling Haskell. But its relatively trickier when the C *doesn't know* that it's calling Haskell, and so you'd need to wrap the Haskell shared library with a C library that invoked and managed the runtime transparently to the program that is preloading the haskell-tsocks library to intercept its normal connect functions.

So I'm sure this can be done -- but it sounds rather painful and complicated, and somewhat expensive in terms of having to link the whole ghc runtime in for this one feature. And frankly, I imagine the code you'd be writing (I haven't inspected the tsocks code itself yet) would largely be FFI calls anyway.

So a Haskell implementation of some element of socks -- a proxy, a client, etc. sounds interesting and potentially useful. But the exact preload magic that tsocks does sounds like a perhaps poor fit.

Bear in mind that there are Haskell hackers that are much better at this stuff than me, more knowledgeable, and more experienced. So they might say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

(Posting as a separate answer, since this is advice unrelated to the FFI)

You probably know this stuff, but in case its useful for anyone...

- Read up on the [Network.Socket](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/latest/doc/html/Network-Socket.html) module
- Search the Haskell Wiki for pages that might help you (like [Applications and libraries/Network](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Network))
- Check out [System Programming in Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/systems-programming-in-haskell.html) and other chapters from RWH
- Ignore the people that say "Haskell is terrible for I/O" - protip: you can just scare them away by saying fancy words like "endofunctor"

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly the answer you were looking for, but instead of re-writing it in Haskell, you could just use the [Foreign Function Interface](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI) to wrap the already-existing C implementation in Haskell types.

Note, one of the few major changes in Haskell 2010 was to officially include the FFI as a language feature. Link: [Haskell 2010 FFI](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html)

Comment: I'm actually not interested in tsocks as it exists, so FFI won't help me.  I'm planning to modify its functionality and looking for a project to practice Haskell on, and wondering if this one is suitable.

Comment: @Alex It may not be the easiest for practice, but if it is something you are interested in, it will almost certainly turn into a valuable programming experience. You could even upload it to hackage.